# How to inverse log of an expression

Tags: logarithms, inverse

I have a formula $$ \log_{10}C= (\log_{10}A - 0.80 \cdot \log_{10}B - 8.40)/0.50 $$
I want to write this down as non-logaritmic. I cannot be sure about the $-0.80\cdot \log_{10}B$ part
It might be one of these:

$$ C= (A - 10^{0.80} \cdot B - 10^{8.40})/10^{0.50} $$
or
$$ C= (A -  B^{0.80} - 10^{8.40})/10^{0.50} $$

Am I correct or totally wrong is there any other correct one?

Comment: $c = (ab^{-0.8}10^{-8.4})^{0.5}$

Comment: $10^{\log_{10}C} = 10^{2\log_{10}A-1.6\log_{10}B - 16.8}$. 

$C = A^2\cdot B^{-1.6}\cdot 10^{-16.8} = \frac{A^2}{10^{16.8}B^{1.6}}$.

Comment: @user317176 I think, you made a small mistake: OP indicated that the RHS of their original expression is divided by $0.5$, not multiplied, so the power should be $2=1/0.5$, not $0.5$ as you wrote. Otherwise, our answers are same.

Comment: @o.spectrum Thanks, I can't correct a comment more than 5 minutes after posting.  Yes, it should all be squared, not square-rooted.

Answer (score 1):

To note, it seems like your knowledge of logarithms and exponents is a bit chaotic.

Let's recall the following properties of  exponents and logarithms, $\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}_+$:

1. $b \neq 1:~ a = b^{\log_b a}$.
2. $a^b \cdot a^c = a^{b+c}$ and $a^b \cdot a^{-c} = a^{b-c}$.
3. $(a^b)^c=(a^c)^b = a^{bc}$.
4. $a\neq 1:~\log_a(bc) = \log_a b+\log_a c$, and $\log_a (b/c) = \log_a b - \log_a c$.
5. $a\neq 1:~\log_a b^c = c\log_a b$.
6. If $a=b$ then $c^a = c^b$.

Knowing the above, we can easily show that:
$$
\log_{10}C = 2\log_{10} A-1.6\log_{10} B -16.8
\\
10^{\log_{10}C} = 10^{2\log_{10} A-1.6\log_{10} B -16.8}
\\
C = \dfrac{10^{\log_{10}A^2}}{10^{\log_{10}B^{1.6}}\cdot 10^{16.8}}
\\
C = \dfrac{A^2}{10^{16.8}\cdot B^{1.6}}
$$
Hope my explanation was clear enough, if you still have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask them in the comment section :)

Comment: Well, it's been a long time that i have used them. I forgot so badly. Thanks for help. BTW i asked some other guys in the department and i kinda found a similar answer. I'll review and go over it.